# Combining two wireless home networks into one topography

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

My current setup is this. We have two apartments

**Network A**
Computer A -> Wireless Router A <- Cable Modem A <- Comcast Internet Subscription A

**Network B**
Computer B -> Wireless Router B <- Cable Modem B <- Comcast Internet Subscription B

I want to create a bridge between A and B such that the two are on the same network. I want to be able to iTunes home sharing, share library, etc between the networks. Therefore Computer A would have one IP address signed to it, say 192.168.1.100 and Computer B would have another IP on the same network 192.168.1.129 or something like that.

I would prefer the bridge be over Wi-Fi as opposed to direct ethernet cable. Is this possible, and if so what's the best solution?

Comment: See this discussion which is almost the same: http://superuser.com/questions/35761/how-can-i-join-two-simple-home-networks-together-using-an-ethernet-cable/35775#35775

Answer (score 1):

You should examine the [linked superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/35761/how-can-i-join-two-simple-home-networks-together-using-an-ethernet-cable/35775#35775) as linked by David

As far as a wifi bridge you would probably need a router running [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/index.php) with [custom iptables](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Iptables_command) to preform the routing between networks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to maintain the 2 separate internet connections, the easiest (and cheapest) way to achieve the goal is fitting an additional network adapter into each PC and connect them with a [crossover network cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). of course you can use 2 WLAN adapters (PCI or USB) and a wireless router (but that's more expensive).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [**WDS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System) but it depends on whether your routers support that feature.